# Directory not created with os.makedirs() if Windows explorer is open

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I am creating an automation framework where everytime my python script will create a log directory structure and delete it in a fresh start. While creating a directory using os.makedirs('path') if I keep open a Windows explorer window with the path or a subdirectory path, I observe that in the next run, I get an IOError. The IOError is coming while transferring files to these log directories through FTP from a remote computer.:

```
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:
```

Is this happening because I have kept opened the window while creating/deleting the directory? Sometimes, I need to check a log and forget to close the window. In the next run I see the test exited because of this error. Please let me know if there is a workaround.

**Edit**: code from comments

```
try: 
    os.makedirs(self.dmparentlogfilepath) 
    os.makedirs(self.buildcleanlogfilepath) 
    os.makedirs(self.buildtestlogfilepath) 
    os.makedirs(self.executelogfilepath) 
    os.makedirs(self.dmlogfilepath) 
    os.makedirs(self.jwrelaylogfilepath) 
    os.makedirs(self.ctrlPC_logfilePath) 
except OSError as exception: 
    if exception.errno != errno.EEXIST: 
        raise
```

Here is the code to delete the tree:

```
 shutil.rmtree(self.dmlogs, ignore_errors = True)
```

Comment: Keeping explorer open might prevent the folder from being deleted.

Comment: Can you post your code?  With my test code, neither creating a subdirectory in a directory I have open, nor deleting a directory I have open throw an error (Windows handles it fine, and pops me automatically to the parent directory).

Comment: @jedwards: Here is my code:

Comment: try:
            os.makedirs(self.dmparentlogfilepath)
            os.makedirs(self.buildcleanlogfilepath)
            os.makedirs(self.buildtestlogfilepath)
            os.makedirs(self.executelogfilepath)
            os.makedirs(self.dmlogfilepath)
            os.makedirs(self.jwrelaylogfilepath)
            os.makedirs(self.ctrlPC_logfilePath)
        except OSError as exception:
            if exception.errno != errno.EEXIST:
                raise

Comment: Not sure if you can view it properly :(

Comment: @user3565150 I edited the code into your question (you can do the same thing) -- make sure it's correct, as I had to guess on indentation and completion

Comment: Well `makedirs()` will raise an exception if you try to create a directory that already exists -- could that be the case?  Also, what about your code for deleting the directories?

Comment: @jedwards, I need to experiment and check whether an exception is raised in os.makedirs fails to create an existing directory since the window is open. The IOerror I am receiving occurs when I fail to do a FTP. shutil,rmtree deletes the directory and I am sure about that. But after that when I call create_directory function, it is not creating a fresh tree